# Return value based on value in different column

Tags: excel-formula

In an excel table, would like to return a value in the column,"Option Year", based on value in different column, "Contract Year".
contract year 2019 should return the text "Base Year"
contract year 2020 should return text "Option 1"
Contract Year 2021 should return text "Option 2"
etc.

Have tried many combinations of this:

```
=choose([@[contractyear]],"Base","Opt 1","Opt 2")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
=IF([@[contractyear]]=2019,"Base Year","Option "&[@[contractyear]]-2019)
```

Comment: That is nice and clean.  My other option was to list each one separately, which would have gotten cumbersome.  Thanks!